# How do I get datatable data to the Modal with angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have created a table which shows employee details. What I want to do is instead of showing all the data in a table, I want to show all details in a modal when a employee row is clicked. I managed to open the modal when a row is clicked but how do I get the data to the modal.

Here's my html

```
<table id="basic-datatables" class="table table-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100">
   <thead style="text-align:match-parent">
       <tr>
           <th rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width:195px">First Name</th>
           <th rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width:195px">Last Name</th>
           <th rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width:200px">Date Of Birth</th>
           <th rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width:100px">Gender</th>
           <th rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width:200px">Email</th>
           <th rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width:100px">Mobile</th>
           <th rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width:190px">Designation</th>
           <th rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width:200px">Date of Join</th>
           <th rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width:195px">NIC</th>
           <th rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width:100px">Dept. Name</th>
       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
       <tr ng-click="selectRow(emp)" ng-repeat="emp in employeeDetails.slice(((currentPage-1)*itemsPerPage),((currentPage)*itemsPerPage))" style="text-align:center">
           <td>{{emp.fname}}</td>
           <td>{{emp.lname}}</td>
           <td>{{emp.DOB | dateFormat}}</td>
           <td>{{emp.gender}}</td>
           <td>{{emp.email}}</td>
           <td>{{emp.mobile_no}}</td>
           <td>{{emp.designation}}</td>
           <td>{{emp.date_of_join | dateFormat}}</td>
           <td>{{emp.nic}}</td>
           <td>{{emp.department_name}}</td>
       </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

and the controller which opens the modal.

```
$scope.selectRow = function (details) {    
            $("#empDetailsModal").modal("show");

        };
```

And finally my modal

```
<div id="empDetailsModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
   <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
       <div class="modal-content">
           <div class="modal-header">
               <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></span></button>
               <h4 class="modal-title">Employee Details</h4>
           </div>
           <div class="modal-body">
               <table id="basic-datatables">
                   <tbody>
                       <tr>
                           <th class="col-md-8">Name:</th>
                           <td>{{emp.fname}}</td>
                       </tr>
                   </tbody>
               </table>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here's the `selectRow()` function is doing the trick. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: you have a functionality which just check which row is clicked and put the same value in modal using scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You you can use separate variable for modal it self, whenever you click any of the row `$scope.modalData` will also got changed and thus your modal :

```
$scope.selectRow = function (details) { 
   $scope.modalData = details
            $("#empDetailsModal").modal("show");

        };
```

And within html:

```
<div id="empDetailsModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
   <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
       <div class="modal-content">
           <div class="modal-header">
               <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></span></button>
               <h4 class="modal-title">Employee Details</h4>
           </div>
           <div class="modal-body">
               <table id="basic-datatables">
                   <tbody>
                       <tr>
                           <th class="col-md-8">Name:</th>
                           <td>{{modalData.fname}}</td>
                       </tr>
                   </tbody>
               </table>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a pop up and set the scope with the scope currently in and set emp    object,

```
  $scope.emp = emp;    
  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('modal.html', {
             scope: $scope               
        }).then(function (modal) {

        });
```